# How to use pd.json_normalize on a list of dictionaries in Pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use the pd.json_normalize() function from the Pandas library on the following data:

```
    data = {
    "examples": [
        {
            "website": "info",
            "df": [
                {
                    "Question": "What?",
                    "Answers": []
                },
                {
                    "Question": "how?",
                    "Answers": []
                },
                {
                    "Question": "Why?",
                    "Answers": []
                }
            ],
     
        },
        {
            "website": "info2",
            "df": [
                {
                    "Question": "What?",
                    "Answers": ["example answer1"]
                },
                {
                    "Question": "how?",
                    "Answers": ["example answer1"]
                },
                {
                    "Question": "Why?",
                    "Answers": ["example answer1"]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to use the following function to filter the data:

```
def filter(data, name):
    resp = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data),
                      pd.json_normalize(data['examples'])],
                     axis=1)
```

The error is occurring on the line pd.json_normalize(data['examples'])]. I believe this is because data['examples'] is a list of dictionaries, rather than a single dictionary.

How can I use pd.json_normalize() on this list of dictionaries in my function?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs in the below line because you don't have any columns called `Answers`. run `resp.columns` before this line to see columns.

```
resp = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(resp),pd.json_normalize(resp['Answers'])],axis=1)
```

Another point is `dropna` took all the data from your dataset, meaning any code after below line is useless because there is no data inside a dataset anymore.

```
resp.dropna(subset=['exResponse.pb_sentence'], inplace=True)
```

Finally, you have a parameter inside your function called `name`, That you have never used. Why does this parameter is there?